# How to I access a class variable that is used by inherited classes in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a main player class which is inherited by two subclasses, bot1 and bot2. In the player class, I want to have a variable to keep track of what action the bot subclasses last took.

```
class player:

    def printstuff(self):
        print self.lastplay.name(self)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self.lastplay = 0
```

main

```
p1 = player.StupidBot("sb") #both of these modify lastplay class variable
p2 = player.RandomBot("rb")
print player.printstuff() #throws error
```

When I run this I get the error below.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'printshit'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = player.StupidBot("sb") #both of these modify lastplay class variable
p2 = player.RandomBot("rb")
print player.printstuff() #throws error
```

`printstuff` is attribute of the inherited classes:

```
print p1.printstuff(), p2.printstuff()
```